# Xcode 13 convenience init compiler issue

Tags: swift, xcode, ios15

Before I updated to Xcode 13 the code below worked fine in another custom UIView created in Xcode 12.
I created this new custom view and the compiler gives the following contradictory errors with reference to the convenience init

1. Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword
2. 'init(frame:)' has already been overridden

Why is Xcode 13 reporting this error in the new custom class but not the identical one created in Xcode 12?

```
class OptionsPanel: UIView {
    
    override init(frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }
    
    convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realise you have declared two initialisers with the exactly same parameter list? I don't believe this compiles in Xcode 12.

Comment: I'm with Sweeper. That shouldn't compile in any version of Xcode. I'd want to know why it works in Xcode 12, not why it doesn't work in Xcode 12. Get rid of the `convenience init(frame:)`. That is a required initializer, not a convenience initializer.

Comment: yes agree that should not compile with xcode 12 either.

Answer (score 0):

That was the problem.  In the other custom view I had other parameters in the convenience init convenience init(frame: CGRect, packages: [Purchases.Package], testing: Bool).
I did try other parameters in this one thinking it might be the problem but had all sorts of issues with the pods Xcode indexing forever until I created a new project and iPhone 13 simulators not showing up.... so it got lost in all that fire fighting!
Thank you Sweeper, Duncan C & Bhawin Ranpura.

I have been asked to edit by Community.
The problem as exactly as answer given -
The convenience init cannot be identical to init. ie

```
override init(frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
}

convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
}
```

Is rejected by the compiler.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).